# cadvisor, elasticsearch, docker: no Elasticsearch node available

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, cadvisor

I'm trying to connect cadvisor to elasticsearch with docker and I'm getting the error:

```
cadvisor.go:113] Failed to initialize storage driver: failed to create the elasticsearch client - no Elasticsearch node available
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
elasticsearch:
    image: "elasticsearch:2.3.3"
    container_name: "elasticsearch"
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
kibana:
    image: "kibana:4.5.1"
    container_name: "kibana"
    ports:
        - "5601:5601"
    links:
        - elasticsearch
cadvisor:
    image: "google/cadvisor:latest"
    container_name: "cadvisor"
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
        - /:/rootfs:ro
        - /var/run:/var/run:rw
        - /sys:/sys:ro
        - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    links:
        - elasticsearch
    restart: always
    command: -storage_driver="elasticsearch" -storage_driver_es_host="http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

If I change the command to

```
command: -storage_driver="elasticsearch" -storage_driver_es_host="http://172.22.0.5:9200"
```

everything works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue (more or less), ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

what you are missing is an index in elasticsearch, unfortunately this is not well documented

go to your kibana dashboard, dev tools and send this request:

`PUT /.kibana/index-pattern/cadvisor
{"title" : "cadvisor",  "timeFieldName": "container_stats.timestamp"}`